# Android : How to get total PSS of all running processes

Tags: android, memory

I am trying to find the relative memory usage of each running application and service using the dalvikPss value as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

As suggested there, I need to sum up all the PSS values of running processes. My question is, how do get the pss values of all running processes ?

My understanding is that services and tasks in Android are linked to processes. Is this understanding correct ?

If so, would summing the PSS values of all processes returned from `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses` give me the total PSS of all running processes (services and tasks included) ?

Comment: I have not. That was to be my last resort since starting a console off the application can have some bad performance implications right ?

And apart from achieving this goal, I also want to know if my understanding that processes represent services and tasks is correct. Do you have any thoughts on that ?

Comment: yes right.then you have i think also  tried using `android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for getting PSS values of all running processes:
use this:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);  
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();  
Map<Integer, String> pidMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();  
for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcesses)  
{  
    pidMap.put(runningAppProcessInfo.pid, runningAppProcessInfo.processName);  
}  
Collection<Integer> keys = pidMap.keySet();  
for(int key : keys)  
{  
    int pids[] = new int[1];  
    pids[0] = key;  
    android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo[] memoryInfoArray = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);  
    for(android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo pidMemoryInfo: memoryInfoArray)  
    {  
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("** MEMINFO in pid %d [%s] **\n",pids[0],pidMap.get(pids[0])));  
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty() + "\n");  
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss() + "\n");  
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty() + "\n");  
    }  
}
```

OR you can also get PSS value using Runtime:

```
    final Process m_process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/top -n 1");
    final StringBuilder sbread = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(m_process.getInputStream()), 8192);
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I saw the first example in another question as well. Are you suggesting that I sum the output of "getTotalPss()" ? What about the value in "dalvikPss" ? Most sources suggest using that value. 

The second answer involves starting a console right ?

Comment: @HeshanPerera : i have these two way for getting PSS value separately for each process then sum up.and second means not start a console which is vsible to user.we just running this command in background

Comment: Thank you again. The latter statement I understand now. But what I dnt understand with the first method is, which value do I sum up ? You get output from three different functions right ? Out of those three functions, which ones do I sum up ?

Comment: @HeshanPerera :getTotalPss() method returning PSS value for each process. see code fist i'm extracting process pid and then passing in getProcessMemoryInfo for each process

Comment: "My understanding is that services and tasks in Android are linked to processes. Is this understanding correct ?"

Could you confirm whether than understanding is correct ?

Comment: Not clear to me using Total pss how one can get actual memory used by process.

Comment: @imrankhan my problem is how I can determine exact memory used by process like xx kb using pss and shared_Dirty and Private_Dirty any idea.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am only getting my app pss value, I am denied to read other running processes. Could you help me